# Does ui:scrollerWrapper have an equivalent in Lightning Web Components?

Tags: lightning-web-components, scrolling

Using slds-scrollable class in Lightning Web Component works in desktop browser but not on Salesforce Mobile app.  For Aura components you would use the ui:scrollerWrapper to accomplish this.  I've tried ui-scroller-wrapper to conform to LWC naming but doesn't seem to be supported.  Hopefully sometime soon.

Comment: What type of element or component are you applying the the slds-scrollable to?

Comment: A div tag.  It works in the browser but I've found documentation saying that slds-scrollable isn't supported in the Salesforce Mobile (Salesforce1) app.  ui:scrollerWrapper is the new preferred method to support scrolling in the mobile app but it doesn't seem to have a corresponding component in Lighting Web Components